# Does groovy have a built-in way to walk / transform a data structure?

Tags: list, dictionary, data-structures, groovy, traversal

Given a nested map/list/scalar data structure in Groovy, does it have any pretty "Groovy" way to walk it and produce a transformed structure?

The cleanest way I've written so far isn't too bad, a recursive walker that applies a closure. But I'd welcome advice if there's a built-in way I am missing.

For example, take this data structure and replace all instances of `${VARIABLE}` with `REPLACED` in `String`s within it:

```
def config = [
  '${VARIABLE}: 'scalar',
  'foo': [
    'bar': 1,
    'baz': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'my_${VARIABLE}_key': null
  ],
  'bak': 1,
  'ban': 'abcd',
  'boo': [
    ['x': 1, 'y': 2, 'subst': '${VARIABLE}'],
    ['a': 1, 'b': 2]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I've come up with so far:

```
def walk(v, Closure transform ) {
  switch (v) {
    case null:
      return null
    case Map:
      return v.collectEntries { mk, mv -> [ transform(mk), walk(mv, transform) ] }
    case List:
      return v.collect { lv -> walk(lv, transform) }
    default:
      return transform(v)
  }
}
```

which given the above example data, may be applied like:

```
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()

def subs = ['VARIABLE': 'REPLACED']

def newconfig = walk(config) { v ->
  switch (v) {
      case String:
        return engine.createTemplate(v).make(subs)
      default:
        return v
  }
}
```

This relies on Groovy's smart `switch` statement. It's not extensible, you can't just plug in your own type handlers, but it's so simple you don't need to. It does a hybrid copy by default, making new instances of `List`s and `Map`s but retaining references to the original scalar or unmatched types. It can be made to deep copy too, per the following identity transform examples:

```
// Identity transform, shallow copy scalars
assert (config == (walk(config) { v -> v.clone() }))

// Identity transform, deep copy scalars where possible
assert (config == (walk(config) {
  v ->
  try {
    return v.clone()
  } catch (java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
    return v
  }
}))
```

Thoughts? Better ways?